# How to use modifiers with custom CSS in NuxtJS and Tailwind (eg. via @layer)

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

**Goal:**
Use a custom style based on the responsive modifier like explained  [here in the tailwind docs:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-custom-utilities).

**What I tried:**

```
$ ~/assets/tailwind.css

@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

@layer utilities {
  .test {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```
$ index.vue

<template>
  <div class="lg:test">Hello</div>
</template>
```

```
$ nuxt.config

tailwindcss: {
  cssPath: '~/assets/tailwind.css',
},
```

**What i expect:**

The div should get a yellow background on large screens.

**What happens instead:**

Nothing at all.

Comment: facing the same situation on a Remix application. My only guess atm is Remix (in your case Nuxt) configuration is messing things up because on their playground it works like the docs

Comment: hi @ElmerDantas - i've set it up differently using this [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs) and it worked. not sure if it helps with your issue in remix though.

Answer (score -1):

I understand this is the question related to nuxt.js, But i would want to help you by giving the overview of how it would work in react.js. So that you get an overview of how things work.

As `tailwind-css` is a mobile first design , it would need explicity indication for medium and large screen devices.

The code goes like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Sample = () => {
  return <div className="bg-green-500 lg:bg-yellow-400 h-screen"></div>;
};

export default Sample;
```

Output:

For larger screens

[image]

For smaller screens

[image]

Comment: OP asks for modifiers with custom CSS